# Syntax error in date in query expression for non-date fields

Tags: ms-access

I'm having trouble building a query in Access 2013. The database isn't mine and the only thing I really have control over is this query. There is a table, I'm pulling 7 fields from it and eventually adding an 8th field to the query to do some string manipulation.

However, I keep getting getting "Syntax error in date in query expression 'fieldname'." error whenever I click on the arrow to sort the fields. The odd thing is these errors pop up when sorting non-date fields. When sorting the date field I get "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Release Date'."

This happens after a fresh build. I have no WHERE conditions, just SELECT and FROM. Ideas?

Here's the sql query, though I'm mainly working in the query design view:

```
SELECT Transmissions.[Job#], Transmissions.[Part#], Transmissions.TransmissionSN, Transmissions.Status, Transmissions.[Release Date], Transmissions.[Build Book Printed], Transmissions.[ID Tags Required]
FROM Transmissions;
```

Comment: I just noticed that the only fields that are giving me trouble are the ones surrounded in brackets. TransmissionSN and Status don't give me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it seems you are the lucky inheritor of a poorly designed database.

Using special characters in a field name is just asking for trouble.  And you've found what that trouble is.

Access uses the `#` sign to designate a Date type for query comparisons.  Such as:

```
dtSomeDate = #2/20/2017#
```

You surround the date with the `#` signs.

In your case, the query thinks `[Job#]` and `[Part#]` are trying to wrap dates.  But of course, that's not the case and thus it fails.

You can try a couple of work arounds.  (I leave it to you to experiment.)

1) You can try to rename the problem fields within your query.  So that:

`Transmissions.[Job#]` becomes `Transmissions.[Job#] as JobNum`

and

`Transmissions.[Part#]` becomes `Transmissions.[Part#] as PartNum`

2) You can try to copy the [Transmissions] table to a new table that you create 
   that does not have the naming problems.

3) Export the [Transmissions] table to a CSV file and re-import it to a new 
   table (or possibly new database) without the naming problems.

Here is a link to a microsoft article that tells you why to avoid special characters in Access:

[Big Bad Special Chars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826763/error-message-when-you-use-special-characters-in-access-databases).

Hope that puts you on the right track. :)

Comment: Thanks. I actually decided to just deal with the data by exporting into excel since excel doesn't care what the column header is so much.

I figured it had something to do with the field names using spaces and pound signs. I forget that # is used for dates (I haven't really had to use that feature yet.) Yeah this is a terrible database. My company has a poor habit of demanding too much from access and using poor technique. We really could use dedicated SQL databases, but the powers that be are too impatient to wait for a proper set up.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this means that the field names are missing or misspelled.

Try running this to see:

```
SELECT * FROM Transmissions;
```

Comment: I find that unlikely as I selected the fields from the table's box in design view (so Access would be the one misspelling it).

That said, I tried asterisk and I still have the same problem.

Comment: The star will return whatever fields there are.